# How to write a script that does collectstatic for django

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, expect

I want to do an automatic collectstatic script for my django application. I tried various things but it did not work. My last attempt is to call an expect script within a normal script:

collectstatic.sh:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --settings=app.settings_mark &&
./testscript.sh
```

testscript.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn testscript.sh
expect "Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:"
send "yes"
```

However, the line `./testscript.sh` get never executed because the `collectstatic` command before is waiting for input. How can I skip that ? I also tried leaving out the `&&` but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It seems to me this question should be at StackOverflow...

Comment: no cause it is clearly a shell script question, all the others questions regarding shell/bash are on askubuntu as well, thanks for watching though !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just send `yes` to the input of `manage.py`:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --settings=app.settings_mark <<<yes &&
./testscript.sh
```

Or:

```
echo yes | python manage.py collectstatic --settings=app.settings_mark &&
./testscript.sh
```

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing with the noinput arg:

manage.py collectstatic --noinput

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705305/automated-django-receive-hook-on-server-respond-to-collectstatic-with-yes

Answer (score 17):

You can try

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```